# Invoke method in DLL with C#

Tags: c#, c++, invoke

How to invoke this method in C# ( it's an method in WD_SDK.dll, it's C++ ) ?

```
WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(HANDLE hChannel, PVOID pContext, VideoCaptureCB_Ptr pCB);
```

Comment: According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e232f033-704e-4ee9-aa4e-e7d2a8491207/c-program-to-call-c-class-in-dll?forum=csharpgeneral), it's not possible but he also suggested a work-around.

Comment: @Nath, what do you mean? That function neither takes nor returns STL containers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I guess I missed that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Most likely those would all be `IntPtr`, but you really need to check the API.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
 [DllImport("yourdll.dll", EntryPoint = "WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB")]
 public static extern void (HANDLE hChannel, PVOID pContext, VideoCaptureCB_Ptr pCB);
```

Comment: VS show an error "The type or namespace name 'PVOID' could not be found"

Comment: use object instead of HANDLE, PVOID and VideoCaptureCB_Ptr.

Comment: try IntPtr instead of HANDLE and PVOID